# How to call a function and add it to another function. python

Tags: python, linked-list

I have three functions that I have been working on. The first function removes the head of a linked list. The second removes the tail from the linked list. The third I need to called remove tail, remove head function, and add it to remove function. The third function goal is to remove values in the middle. The code right now prints out all of the numbers instead of slowly taking the tail off.

I would like to call this function within remove function.

```
def remove_tail(self):        
        if self.head is  None:
            return None
        removed_tail = self.tail
        if removed_tail == self.head:  
            self.head = None
            self.tail = None
        else:
          current = self.head
        while current.next != self.tail:
            current = current.next
        removed_tail = current
        current.next = None
        self. Tail = current
```

```
def remove(self, value, remove_tail):
        curr = self.head
        while curr is not None:
            if curr.data == value:
                # If the location of 'value' is at the end of the list,
                # then we can call insert_tail to add 'new_value'
                if curr == self.tail:
                    self.insert_tail(value)
                else:
                    new_node = LinkedList.Node(value)
                    new_node.prev = curr       
                    new_node.next = curr.next  
                    curr.next.prev = new_node 
                    curr.next = new_node       
                return # We can exit the function after we insert
            curr = curr.next # Go to the next node to search for 'value'
```

I was trying to see if I could take self. Tail and add remove tail function to it. If current is equal to self. Tail it seems to me I can added remove tail to it?
if curr == self.tail:
self.insert_tail(value)

Comment: I can't figure out what you mean by "adding" a function to another function.  Can you describe what you want the final effect to be?

Comment: How can I call the function remove_tail and connect it to the remove function?

Comment: How can I call the function remove_tail and connect it to the remove function? Is there a way you can use more than one function while creating a program?

Comment: Yes, you can call whatever functions you want in a program.  Changing the word "add" to "connect" doesn't make your intent any clearer.  What do you actually want to have happen?  How does `remove_tail` relate to `remove`?  If you need to remove an element in the middle of a linked list, removing the tail isn't a good first step because you'd need to do that an arbitrary number of times and then carefully re-add all the nodes you removed.  It's much easier to just iterate through the list and remove only the node you want to remove.

Comment: *"The code right now prints out all of the numbers"*: you have not shared any code that prints. It is not clear what you are asking. Then you bring in `self.insert_tail`. What exactly is the question? Also `remove_tail` references `current` when it might not have been defined yet. Maybe an indentation error.

Comment: I solved the error. Everything works fine now. I had to change everything.

Comment: @BigEdit if you solved the problem, consider posting a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to help other people with the same problem as you, or close the question if it won't help anyone else. Thanks.